# What dotnet target generations would the Mono and Xamarin iOS & Android runtimes support?

Tags: .net, xamarin, mono

What dotnet target [.NET Platform Generations](https://github.com/davidfowl/aspnetvnextwebapiapp/blob/master/Generations.md) would the Mono and Xamarin iOS & Android runtimes support? This chart is currently missing them and needs some help to complete it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post has since been updated to include xamarin and mono. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

Comment: Thank you! I noticed your tweet had up-to-date links. https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/662181994684518400

Comment: Document moved to: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK; That's a bit like asking "what version of javascript does Chrome support?". The answer? Well, they conform to ES5 at least, and have started to implement ES2015. So, they are somewhere inbetween. Also, they support a number of APIs that have been raised for ES2016 or later.

With regard to your question on what version of dotnet mono suuports, there might not be a binary (or numerical) answer. They support what APIs they've managed to implement, which I think is most of them. Disclaimer: Been a while since I looked at this, and things might have changed. Also, I¨m not affiliated with anyone in any way. So I might not know what I'm talking about :P.